# UITableView with Tag in TouchBegin

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have UIViewController with UITableView and i give the view in the UIViewController tag of 3 for example.now i want to recognize this tag number in the TouchBegin method :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint finger = [touch locationInView:self];
    int x = finger.x;
    int y = finger.y;

    int z = self.tag;
}
```

and the problem is that the z is always 0,how i can modify it to work?

Comment: Can you post some more code? The context isn't clear here.

Comment: this is the code,in the viewDidLoad i put : self.view.tag = 3; . and then i write the touchBegan method and want to get this tag number and i always get 0 when i touch the UITableView

Comment: where is this code? what are you trying to do?

Comment: do you implement this code in your UIView subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told us that you put self.view.tag = 3, which means that it's the UIView in your UIViewController that has been assigned a tag of 3. Then in touchesBegan, you ask for the tag in the UIViewController, which doesn't make sense. Try int z = self.view.tag.